# PHP while loop and array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to loop through some CSV data and take out the $data[4] item.  My eventual goal is to find the average and hopefully use PHP's array_sum.  This seems to be working, except that every time I try and create this array, my while loop breaks each value into their own separate arrays ($real), not one array that I can work with.  I have tried everything, including working with the arrays outside of the loop, but nothing has worked.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
    $symbol=array("XOM","CVX","RDS-A",
                 "PTR","TOT","SNP","COP",
                 "IMO","BP","E","STO","EC","SU","MRO");
    for($i=0; $i<count($symbol);$i++)
    {
        $handle = @fopen("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={$symbol[$i]}&a=10&b=12&c=2013&d=10&e=12&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv", "r", false, $context);
        if ($handle === false)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error("Could not connect to Yahoo!", E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }

        // download title of CSV file and throw away
        $data=fgetcsv($handle);

        //loop through data
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !==FALSE)

        {

            $rows++;
            $num=count($data);
            $real=array($data[4]);



        }
            var_dump($real);

    }
```

And here's my final output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "92.669998" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "120.00" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "66.290001" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "111.059998" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "58.73" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "82.449997" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "72.82" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "42.740002" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "45.91" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "47.98" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "22.440001" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "41.93" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "34.82" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "35.82" }
```

Comment: Can you post a little more code, `$symbol` specifically, so we can test?

Comment: Also, you should provide current output

Comment: instead of this `$real=array($data[4]);` try this `$real[] = $data[4]`

Comment: hey guys, just posted the output and the value $symbol.  and tried Riggsfolly solution.  still no luck :/  But i'm also very new at php, so I could also be interpreting the data incorrectly.

Comment: What do you actually want the output to look like please

Comment: I want it to be an array that I can work with, ex: find the sum of all the values by using array_sum or anything similar to that

Comment: I can post the full function, including opening the connection to yahoo if that would be more helpful.

Comment: No show a simple example of what you want the `$real` array to look like

Comment: `array(14) {
[0]=>string(9) "92.669998" 
[1]=>string(6) "120.00"
etc                                                                                                                           }`

Comment: Just a couple of nit-picks...  I'd prefer to use `foreach($symbol as $thisSymbol)` instead of a regular for loop with an index; it's what `foreach` is intended for - works for both associative and numerically indexed arrays.  If you _must_ use a traditional for loop, avoid calling `count` every time the loop iterates - there's function call overhead in doing that and it's better for performance to declare a variable like `$symbolCount = count($symbol);` before the loop and then use `for($i = 0; $i < $symbolCount; $i++)`

Comment: Spot on @MatteoC, I especially don't see enough people setting their count outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what `$context` is, but try this...

```
$symbol=array("XOM","CVX","RDS-A","PTR","TOT","SNP","COP","IMO","BP","E","STO","EC","SU","MRO");
$datas = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($symbol);$i++){
    $handle = @fopen("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={$symbol[$i]}&a=10&b=12&c=2013&d=10&e=12&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv", "r", false, $context);
    if ($handle === false){
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        trigger_error("Could not connect to Yahoo!", E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }

    // download title of CSV file and throw away
    $data=fgetcsv($handle);

    //loop through data
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !==FALSE){
        $rows++;
        $datas[] = $data[4];
    }
}

print_r($datas);
```

Comment: Is that not basically what I said in a comment 14minutes ago, and the questioner said was not what he wanted?

Comment: Well I didnt see your comment, but replacing the array each loop, as it was done in his original code won't help him much when he wants to work with all of those numbers to get averages. So I am interested in him moving the array out of the loop and seeing what his result is. Let's get him a bit close and see where we can take him from here.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Still get the same result however.  I'm trying to aim for: `array(14) { [0]=>string(9) "92.669998" [1]=>string(6) "120.00" etc }`

Comment: What is the output of `$datas`? Your original output showed each value in a separate array, mine _should_ have put them all into an array (similar to what you just posted in your comment). So, seeing what did output would be helpful. Also if you want to post what `$context` is, I should be able to run this locally.

Comment: I got something a bit closer, but it makes a new array everytime, adding each number, with every run of the loop.  `array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "92.669998" } array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "92.669998" [1]=> string(6) "120.00" } array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "92.669998" [1]=> string(6) "120.00" [2]=> string(9) "66.290001" } array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "92.669998" [1]=> string(6) "120.00" [2]=> string(9) "66.290001" [3]=> string(10) "111.059998" }` I can't post all of the answer(due to space limits), but it keeps going until the array I want is at the end

Comment: haha, that's what I tried before and just had the same problem again!  argh, its pretty annoying.  I'll keep trying to put it on ideone.

Comment: Well, I feel stupid.  After playing around with it more,  you guys were correct in the declaration.  I had some small typos on my end, but quickly resolved it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, don't we have all been there! Heck, i'll be there later today ;)

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate the help!